# using cursor within a cursor in SQL -oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I was looking online to see if i can find an example of how cursors (within a cursor ) can be used for my desired results from 2 tables but no success. So i was wondering if any can point me to examples or help me with my code.

Data: from 2 tables

```
DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME    
------------- --------------------
           10 ACCOUNTING           
           50 EXECUTIVE            
           40 IT                   
           60 MARKETING            
           20 RESEARCH             
           30 SALES
```

6 rows selected

```
EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME            SALARY DEPARTMENT_ID    MAX_SAL   MAX75SAL
----------- -------------------- ---------- ------------- ---------- ----------
       8000 BREWSTER                   2500                     2500       1875 
       7603 CLARK                      4000            50       5000       3750 
       7900 FISHER                     3000            30       3000       2250 
       7921 JACKSON                    2500            30       3000       2250 
       7566 JONES                      3000            10       3000       2250 
       7596 JOST                       4500            50       5000       3750 
       7839 KING                       5000            50       5000       3750 
       7944 LEE                        2400            20       3000       2250 
       7788 SCOTT                      2500            40       2900       2175 
       7910 SMITH                      2900            40       2900       2175 
       7886 STEEL                      2500            10       3000       2250 
       7610 WILSON                     3000            20       3000       2250 
       7999 WOLFE                      2500            20       3000       2250
```

At first i was getting this results:

```
ACCOUNTING              3000            2250      JONES
ACCOUNTING              3000            2250      STEEL
EXECUTIVE               5000            3750      CLARK
EXECUTIVE               5000            3750       JOST
EXECUTIVE               5000            3750       KING
IT                      2900            2175      SCOTT
IT                      2900            2175      SMITH
RESEARCH                3000            2250        LEE
RESEARCH                3000            2250     WILSON
RESEARCH                3000            2250      WOLFE
SALES                   3000            2250     FISHER
SALES                   3000            2250    JACKSON
N/A                     2500            1875   BREWSTER
```

But I need them to come out like:

```
ACCOUNTING              3000            2250      JONES STEEL
EXECUTIVE               5000            3750      CLARK JOST KING
IT                      2900            2175      SCOTT SMITH
RESEARCH                3000            2250        LEE WILSON WOLFE
SALES                   3000            2250     FISHER JACKSON
```

Where EVERY department name will ONLY  yield ONE row, but with the names of the employees who match the criteria at the end.

My code:

```
DECLARE
-- First cursor 
CURSOR c_get_dept IS
        SELECT      department_id, department_name 
    FROM            department
ORDER BY        department_name;

-- Second cursor 
CURSOR c_get_emp (p_dept_id NUMBER) IS

select  z.employee_id, z.employee_name, z.salary, z.department_id,
max_sal,(z.max_sal *.75)  max75sal
from
(
SELECT employee_id, employee_name,salary,department_id, 
max(salary) over (partition by department_id) as max_sal
FROM        employee
ORDER BY employee_name
) z
WHERE salary > (max_sal*.75 )
order by z.employee_name;

v_flag NUMBER;
BEGIN
-- Open first cursor
FOR idx_1 IN c_get_dept LOOP
        v_flag := 0;
-- Open second cursor `
        FOR idx_2 IN c_get_emp(idx_1.department_id) LOOP
            IF v_flag = 0 THEN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(idx_1.department_name || '   ' || idx_2.max_sal ||
                '   ' || idx_2.max75sal || '   ' || idx_2.EMPLOYEE_NAME);
                v_flag := 0;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
IF v_flag = 0 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  No output.');
    END IF;

 END LOOP;
 END;
```

thank you!

Comment: Deleted my "answer" per other folks point that it's not an answer, but about clarifying.  To summarize: You're in for a brutal time trying to get this working with cursors.  Not that it can't be done, but restructuring the data and using BI layer functionality is far better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Oracle 11.2 you have the LISTAGG function ([reference here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php)) which can help with what you're trying to do. The following query produces the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
       MAX(e.SALARY) AS MAX_SALARY,
       MAX(e.SALARY)*0.75 AS MAX75,
       LISTAGG(e.EMPLOYEE_NAME, ' ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d.DEPARTMENT_NAME) AS EMPLOYEES
  FROM DEPARTMENT d
  INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e
    ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
  GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
  ORDER BY d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e9e8/14)

If the goal of this is to use multiple cursors in a PL/SQL block I suggest trying something simple like the following (note and warning: untested code follows):

```
DECLARE
  nDepartment_max_salary  NUMBER;
  strEmployees            VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR dept IN (SELECT *
                 FROM DEPARTMENT
                 ORDER BY DEPARTMENT_NAME)
  LOOP
    nDepartment_max_salary := 0;
    strEmployees := NULL;

    FOR emp IN (SELECT *
                  FROM EMPLOYEE e
                  WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID = dept.DEPARTMENT_ID)
    LOOP
      nDepartment_max_salary := GREATER(nDepartment_max_salary, emp.SALARY);
      strEmployees := strEmployees || emp.EMPLOYEE_NAME || ' ';
    END LOOP; -- emp

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dept.DEPARTMENT_NAME || '   ' ||
                         nDepartment_max_salary || '   ' ||
                         nDepartment_max_salaray * 0.75 || '   ' ||
                         strEmployees);
  END LOOP;  -- dept
END;
```

Share and enjoy.